# How are input events associated to Views?

Tags: android, view, touch-event

How does an android application associate and input event with a view specifically speaking which class and which method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the screen is touched, a MotionEvent is dispatched to the top most View (the content view of the Activity). The content view then does some calculations on area and determines if it has children that are able to receive the MotionEvent and passes the MotionEvent to the View that the MotionEvent falls into via a `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`. This is repeated down the View heirarchy until a view return true or the MotionEvent comes back to the top level View at which point it decides to either handle or discard it.
Refer to :

[View#onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

[ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Comment: What i was hoping for that there is a method like method(view, event) that gets executed im trying to find a place to intercept both event and the view it is being delieverd to ... im not talking about listeners

Comment: The sdk says that the window manages the input that comes from the system into the application i have the android source code can you point me to where all this happens?

Comment: Well, onInterceptTouch catches a MotionEvent, but  doesn't tell you were it is going (you intercepted it after all). Before I go further though, what are you trying to do? Why do you need to know destination and event if you are not passing it to a listener?

Comment: Im trying to understand how the framework works i have downloaded the source code and im tracing how input is dispatched to  a view. So far i understand that activity implements a callback interface for dispatching methods like dispatchtoucheven but this parameter only has a motion event my question is where exactly does a view get associated with  a view specifically speaking which class and which methods. Thanks!

Comment: In the onTouchEvent of a ViewGroup. The method does all the calculations for determining immediate child sizes and dispatched the MotionEvent to the correct child.

Comment: Correct sizes of a View are determined by it's on measure and the LayoutParams associated to the View.

Answer (score 0):

It uses Observer/Listener pattern. You implement specific interface and then register with Android platform. This is how Android platform knows which class and which method to call.

Since we are using interface as a medium, so Android platform knows which methods to call. The class is what you provide, either by creating anonymous inner classes or full fledged classes.

Example:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // You code
        }
    });
```

Now here Android will call View.OnClickListener interface method and you are passing the actual instance of class as an argument.